# how can I reset robot localization in runtime

Tags: ros2, robot-localization

I'm using ros2 iron and robot_localization with dual EKF and navsat on an outdoor rover. After some time of working I would like to reset the filter as if I turn it off and re-launch it. Is there a way to do that?
robot-localization is launching inside a docker container with some other packages so it's no easy to restart it.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *set_pose* service to re-localize the robot. If you want more information, you can watch the source code [here](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/5140f979eb1a1d2fa8433f57b2d0a37c5360e50a/src/ros_filter.cpp#L2287)

About the service the [ros2 documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Understanding-ROS2-Services/Understanding-ROS2-Services.html) is very helpfully